Dynamic JavaScript import fails sometimes
I have some JavaScript files in my directory. So, instead of loading scripts using <script>  tag I am loading the scripts using import statement. While doing like this sometimes error is occurring while evaluating the variable in the imported file.
Error occured ReferenceError: navTimeData2 is not defined
This failure can happen randomly on any variable from navTimeData1 to navTimeData6.
I am using the below function to import the files based on the path in the JSON File.
JSON File Content
var scriptsDetail = {
    "Performance Evaluation": {
    "ScriptsDetail": [
      {
        "Build - Environment": "Build_001",
        "TestScriptName": "HCIS01_QuickRegistration",
        "Perf Metrics Detail": [          
          {
            "Run ID": "Run_Build_001_1",
            "Navigation Time Report": "../../../PerMetrics/HCIS01_QuickRegistration/Run_Build_001-1/HCIS01_QuickRegistration_NavigationTime.js",
            "Paint Time Report": "../../../PerMetrics/HCIS01_QuickRegistration/Run_Build_001-1/HCIS01_QuickRegistration_PaintTime.js",
            "Long Task Report": "../../PerMetrics/HCIS01_QuickRegistration/Run_Build_001-1/HCIS01_QuickRegistration_LongTask.js",
            "LCP Report": "../../PerMetrics/HCIS01_QuickRegistration/Run_Build_001-1/HCIS01_QuickRegistration_LCP.js"
          },
          {
            "Run ID": "Run_Build_001_2",
            "Navigation Time Report": "../../../PerMetrics/HCIS01_QuickRegistration/Run_Build_001-2/HCIS01_QuickRegistration_NavigationTime.js",
            "Paint Time Report": "../../../PerMetrics/HCIS01_QuickRegistration/Run_Build_001-2/HCIS01_QuickRegistration_PaintTime.js",
            "Long Task Report": "../../../PerMetrics/HCIS01_QuickRegistration/Run_Build_001-2/HCIS01_QuickRegistration_LongTask.js",
            "LCP Report": "../../../PerMetrics/HCIS01_QuickRegistration/Run_Build_001-2/HCIS01_QuickRegistration_LCP.js"
          },
          {
            "Run ID": "Run_Build_001_3",
            "Navigation Time Report": "../../../PerMetrics/HCIS01_QuickRegistration/Run_Build_001-3/HCIS01_QuickRegistration_NavigationTime.js",
            "Paint Time Report": "../../../PerMetrics/HCIS01_QuickRegistration/Run_Build_001-3/HCIS01_QuickRegistration_PaintTime.js",
            "Long Task Report": "../../PerMetrics/HCIS01_QuickRegistration/Run_Build_001-3/HCIS01_QuickRegistration_LongTask.js",
            "LCP Report": "../../PerMetrics/HCIS01_QuickRegistration/Run_Build_001-3/HCIS01_QuickRegistration_LCP.js"
          },
          {
            "Run ID": "Run_Build_001_4",
            "Navigation Time Report": "../../../PerMetrics/HCIS01_QuickRegistration/Run_Build_001-4/HCIS01_QuickRegistration_NavigationTime.js",
            "Paint Time Report": "../../../PerMetrics/HCIS01_QuickRegistration/Run_Build_001-4/HCIS01_QuickRegistration_PaintTime.js",
            "Long Task Report": "../../PerMetrics/HCIS01_QuickRegistration/Run_Build_001-4/HCIS01_QuickRegistration_LongTask.js",
            "LCP Report": "../../PerMetrics/HCIS01_QuickRegistration/Run_Build_001-4/HCIS01_QuickRegistration_LCP.js"
          },
          {
            "Run ID": "Run_Build_001_5",
            "Navigation Time Report": "../../../PerMetrics/HCIS01_QuickRegistration/Run_Build_001-5/HCIS01_QuickRegistration_NavigationTime.js",
            "Paint Time Report": "../../../PerMetrics/HCIS01_QuickRegistration/Run_Build_001-5/HCIS01_QuickRegistration_PaintTime.js",
            "Long Task Report": "../../../PerMetrics/HCIS01_QuickRegistration/Run_Build_001-5/HCIS01_QuickRegistration_LongTask.js",
            "LCP Report": "../../../PerMetrics/HCIS01_QuickRegistration/Run_Build_001-5/HCIS01_QuickRegistration_LCP.js"
          },
          {
            "Run ID": "Run_Build_001_6",
            "Navigation Time Report": "../../../PerMetrics/HCIS01_QuickRegistration/Run_Build_001-6/HCIS01_QuickRegistration_NavigationTime.js",
            "Paint Time Report": "../../../PerMetrics/HCIS01_QuickRegistration/Run_Build_001-6/HCIS01_QuickRegistration_PaintTime.js",
            "Long Task Report": "../../../PerMetrics/HCIS01_QuickRegistration/Run_Build_001-6/HCIS01_QuickRegistration_LongTask.js",
            "LCP Report": "../../../PerMetrics/HCIS01_QuickRegistration/Run_Build_001-6/HCIS01_QuickRegistration_LCP.js"
          },
        ]

JSON File is read in another JavaScript file and imported using the below function.
var scriptsData = this.scriptsDetail['Performance Evaluation']['ScriptsDetail'];
    
scriptsData.forEach((script)=>{
    let data = script['Perf Metrics Detail']
    var iter=0
    const navigationReports = [];
    for (const item of data) {
      navigationReports.push({
        "Run ID": item["Run ID"],
        "Navigation Time Report": item["Navigation Time Report"]
      });
    }
    
    let navTimeReportArray=null;
    
    const importPromises = navigationReports.map((navReport)=>{
                    
        return import(navReport['Navigation Time Report']).then((module) => {
            
            iter+=1
            console.log(iter)
            var navTimeDataVar = eval("navTimeData"+iter);
            if(navTimeReportArray===null){
                
                navTimeReportArray = navTimeDataVar
            }
            else {
                navTimeReportArray = navTimeReportArray.concat(navTimeDataVar)
            }
            
            //Process_NavTimeData(script['Transaction Detail'],script['Test Script Name'])
        }).catch((err)=>{
            console.log("Error occured", err);
        })
        
        
    })
})

JavaScript sample content is as below. The files are placed inside the path mentioned in the JSON file.
window.navTimeData2=[
  {
    "unloadEventStart": 0,
    "unloadEventEnd": 0,
    "domInteractive": 4383.0999999940395,
    "domContentLoadedEventStart": 4389,
    "domContentLoadedEventEnd": 4392.0999999940395,
    "domComplete": 4392.5999999940395,
    "loadEventStart": 4392.699999988079,
    "loadEventEnd": 4394.399999976158,
    "type": "navigate",
    "redirectCount": 0,
    "criticalCHRestart": 0,
    "activationStart": 0,
    "toJSON": {},
    "initiatorType": "navigation",
    "nextHopProtocol": "http/1.1",
    "deliveryType": "",
    "workerStart": 0,
    "redirectStart": 0,
    "redirectEnd": 0,
    "fetchStart": 3.199999988079071,
    "domainLookupStart": 3.199999988079071,
    "domainLookupEnd": 3.199999988079071,
    "connectStart": 3.199999988079071,
    "connectEnd": 3.199999988079071,
    "secureConnectionStart": 0,
    "requestStart": 7.399999976158142,
    "responseStart": 32.29999998211861,
    "responseEnd": 402.09999999403954,
    "transferSize": 73860,
    "encodedBodySize": 73560,
    "decodedBodySize": 73560,
    "serverTiming": [],
    "responseStatus": 200,
    "firstInterimResponseStart": 0,
    "renderBlockingStatus": "non-blocking",
    "entryType": "navigation",
    "startTime": 0,
    "duration": 4394.399999976158,
    "TransactionName": "HCIS_Login",
    "TransactionStartTime": "09/05/2024 00:09:37.698",
    "transactionEndTime": "09/05/2024 00:09:37.706",
    "RunID": "Run_Build_001-6",
    "ScriptID": "HCIS01_QuickRegistration",
    "resourceName": "/menu.jsp"
  }
]

